# What is the name of the inequality $\|\int_{\mathcal X} f(x) dx\| \leq \int_{\mathcal X} \|f(x)\| dx$

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

Let $x \in {\mathcal X} \subseteq {\mathbb R}^n$ and $f: {\mathcal X} \to {\mathcal X}$. Then what is the name of the following inequality?

$$\left\|\int_{\mathcal X} f(x) dx\right\| \leq \int_{\mathcal X} \|f(x)\| dx$$

Thanks!

Comment: It has no common name, just the property of norm and integral.

Comment: You may call it the triangle inequality (it can be seen as a generalization of the usual triangle inequality).

Comment: Positivity of the integral. $g\ge 0 \Rightarrow \int g \ge 0$. In your case $g= \|f\|\pm f$.

Comment: Hi Hasek, Joel Cohen, and Fnacool. Thanks very much for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably call it "Jensen's Inequality" if I used it in a paper.  But of course Jensen's Inequality is in fact more general:
$$
\phi\left(\int_{\mathcal X} f(x) dx\right) \leq \int_{\mathcal X} \phi\big(f(x)\big) dx
$$
where $\phi$ is a convex function.

**note**
As Ian notes, this form of Jensen requires that $\mathcal X$ have measure $1$.

Comment: Jensen' inequality makes so much more sense now

Comment: I don't think I agree here because this property holds regardless of what the total measure of $\mathcal{X}$ is (even if it is infinite). By contrast, Jensen's inequality, stated in this form, hinges on the measure in question being a probability measure. As an example, consider the Lebesgue measure on $[0,2]$, $\phi(x)=x^2$, $f(x)=1$. In this case the left side is $4$ and the right side is $2$. Of course Jensen's inequality has a restatement for any finite measure, but this basically amounts to switching our attention to the normalization of the finite measure anyway.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! [+1]